# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dual Boot with Windows 8.1)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am not familiar with Ubuntu, BIOS, Windows and other definitions.

I have a laptop with a Toshiba MQ Hard Drive. The hard drive already has two partitions, one with NTFS for Windows and the other RAW. (Unknown Chinese word for me). Anyway, I checked and I don't have an EFI partition. I downloaded Ubuntu in a USB stick and now I want to install it. I have already tried and lost everything that I had in Windows. I had to format the hard drive. Now with two partitions, how can I install it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any data on your drive, try to start from scratch, meaning with no partitions at all.

- Install Windows at first (it will install a EFI Partition as well)
- Boot into the Ubuntu installation (via Stick or DVD)
- Choose custom installation
- Shrink the windows partition to the wished size
- Define your Ubuntu partitions
- Install

That should be it. You should be able to boot into both systems from the EFI menu during startup.